# How to kill 5 processes at the same time - BATCH

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Is there a way to kill several processes faster?

```
TASKKILL /F /IM process1.exe
TASKKILL /F /IM process2.exe
TASKKILL /F /IM process3.exe
TASKKILL /F /IM process4.exe
TASKKILL /F /IM process5.exe
```

Instead of waiting for the previous process to finish, finish them at the same time, or is it not possible in this way? I tried using a single line with "&" but it is the same, sequential.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `bash`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that using just one single instance of `taskkill.exe`:

```bash
%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /Im "Process*.exe" /F
```

Or, as I'm certain you've not been truthful about the names of your processes:

```bash
%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /Fi "ImageName Eq Process1.exe" /Fi "ImageName Eq Process2.exe" /Fi "ImageName Eq Process3.exe" /Fi "ImageName Eq Process4.exe" /Fi "ImageName Eq Process5.exe" /F
```

Even if you were satisfied with multiple `taskkill.exe` instances you could still use a loop, instead of writing out five individual command lines.

Directly in [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```bash
For %G In ("Process1.exe" "Process2.exe" "Process3.exe" "Process4.exe" "Process5.exe") Do @Start "Kill %~nG" SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /Im "%~G" /F
```

In a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```bash
@For %%G In ("Process1.exe" "Process2.exe" "Process3.exe" "Process4.exe" "Process5.exe") Do @Start "Kill %%~nG" SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /Im "%%~G" /F
```

Answer (score 1):

Dave. I think you can use start to run commands parallel. Something like this:

```
start "" TASKKILL /F /IM process1.exe
start "" TASKKILL /F /IM process2.exe
start "" TASKKILL /F /IM process3.exe
start "" TASKKILL /F /IM process4.exe
start "" TASKKILL /F /IM process5.exe
```

Here is some more information for you:

- Using **&** you will run both commands no matter what happens.
- Using **&&** you will run the second command after the success of the first command
- Using **||** you will run the second command after the first one fails to execute.